# ggplot2 output in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am struggling to find a way to connect the input variable that I have named "plot1" to the actual reactive variable I have made.  I know how to do this with ggvis (bind_shiny function), but I am working with ggplot for the first time and do not know how to do this.  I know the code contained within the reactive variable vis works as a standalone without the reactive component.  Any help is much appreciated!  Sample code is below.

```
#Check packages to use in library
{
  library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used
  library('ggplot2')
  library('dplyr')
  library('stringr') #string opperator
  library('dplyr')
  library('RSQLite')
}

#Data

horizontal_position <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)
vertical_position <- c(-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

ID_no <- 1
data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
ID_1 <-data.frame(ID_no, horizontal_position, vertical_position, data_val)

ID_no <- 2
data_val <- sample(0:100, 25)
ID_2 <-data.frame(ID_no, horizontal_position, vertical_position, data_val)

all_data <-rbind(ID_1, ID_2)
IDchoices <- as.character(unique(all_data$ID_no))

# UI

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
   column(2,
           wellPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = "ID", label="Select ID:", choices = IDchoices, selected = "1", multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)
          )
           )
    ),
    column(9,
           wellPanel(plotOutput("plot1")
          ))
 )

#SERVER

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
 filteredData <- reactive({
   m <- all_data %>% filter(
     ID_no %in% input$ID
    )
   m
 })
 vis <- reactive({          
      p1 = filteredData() %>%
      ggplot(aes(horizontal_position, vertical_position)) +
      geom_tile(aes(fill = data_val)) + 
      geom_text(aes(label = data_val),colour="white")
  })
}

#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: `employee, date, type, model, num_1` are missing in `ID_1`

Comment: Just replace `vis <- reactive({` with `output$plot1 <- renderPlot({`

Comment: @HubertL apologies for not removing those variables in ID_1, that was some extraneous code that I cut out to simplify it for the post, but it must have still been loaded in my environment when I ran it before posting.  As for your second comment, that puts a plot in the wellPanel, but the plot itself is still not populating with no error messages appearing.  The code has been revised to reflect the errant variable definition.

Comment: @HubertL removing the definition of the variable p1 has corrected the issue.  

That part now reads:


output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
          filteredData() %>% ...

Thank you for your help!